# Hilt Fragment has to be attached to @AndroidEntryPoint Activity, while testing (it is attached to @AndEntPoint marked activity)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-testing, robolectric, dagger-hilt

I followed a lot of tutorials/ articles and the [googles architecture sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples)

No matter what I try I keep getting an error saying that I need to attach Fragment to @AndroidEntryPoint annotated Activity. I've setup everything correctly but still can't get this to work properly.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Hilt Fragments must be attached to an @AndroidEntryPoint Activity. Found: class com.nikolam.colorme.HiltTestActivity
    at dagger.hilt.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:83)
    at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.FragmentComponentManager.createComponent(FragmentComponentManager.java:75)
    at dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.FragmentComponentManager.generatedComponent(FragmentComponentManager.java:64)
    at com.nikolam.main_feature.presenter.main_screen.Hilt_MainFragment.generatedComponent(Hilt_MainFragment.java:80)
    at com.nikolam.main_feature.presenter.main_screen.Hilt_MainFragment.inject(Hilt_MainFragment.java:102)
    at com.nikolam.main_feature.presenter.main_screen.Hilt_MainFragment.initializeComponentContext(Hilt_MainFragment.java:63)
    at com.nikolam.main_feature.presenter.main_screen.Hilt_MainFragment.onAttach(Hilt_MainFragment.java:55)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onAttach(Fragment.java:1783)
    at com.nikolam.main_feature.presenter.main_screen.Hilt_MainFragment.onAttach(Hilt_MainFragment.java:45)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performAttach(Fragment.java:2911)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.attach(FragmentStateManager.java:464)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:275)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1971)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:305)
    at com.nikolam.colorme.main_feature.MainFragmentTest$whenMainActivityLaunchedNavigatorIsInvokedForFragment$$inlined$launchFragmentInHiltContainer$1.perform(HiltExt.kt:46)
    at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.lambda$onActivity$2$ActivityScenario(ActivityScenario.java:660)
    at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario$$Lambda$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.onActivity(ActivityScenario.java:670)
    at com.nikolam.colorme.main_feature.MainFragmentTest.whenMainActivityLaunchedNavigatorIsInvokedForFragment(MainFragmentTest.kt:85)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at dagger.hilt.android.internal.testing.MarkThatRulesRanRule$1.evaluate(MarkThatRulesRanRule.java:106)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:575)
    at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.lambda$evaluate$0(SandboxTestRunner.java:263)
    at org.robolectric.internal.bytecode.Sandbox.lambda$runOnMainThread$0(Sandbox.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Now here is my setup.

Dependencies

```
    testImplementation(TestLibraryDependency.HILT_ANDROID_TESTING)
    kaptTest(TestLibraryDependency.HILT_ANDROID_TESTING_COMPILER)
    testImplementation(TestLibraryDependency.TEST_RUNNER)
    testImplementation(TestLibraryDependency.ESPRESSO_CORE)
    testImplementation(TestLibraryDependency.ANDROIDX_TEST_RULES)
    testImplementation(TestLibraryDependency.ANDROIDX_CORE_TESTING)
    testImplementation(TestLibraryDependency.ANDROIDX_TEST_EXT)
```

This is my test

```
@HiltAndroidTest
@Config(application = HiltTestApplication::class, maxSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class MainFragmentTest {

    @get:Rule()
    var hiltAndroidRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Before
    fun init() {
        hiltAndroidRule.inject()
    }

    @Test
    fun whenMainActivityLaunchedNavigatorIsInvokedForFragment() {
     //   launchActivity()
        // GIVEN - On the home screen
        val navController = mock(NavController::class.java)

        var fragment = launchFragmentInHiltContainer<MainFragment>() {
            Navigation.setViewNavController(this.view!!, navController)
        }

        // WHEN - Click on the "+" button
        onView(withId(R.id.add_floating_action)).perform(ViewActions.click())

        // THEN - Verify that we navigate to the add screen
        verify(navController).navigate(
            Uri.parse(UPLOAD_DEEPLINK)
        )
    }
```

[Launch in hilt container per google](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-hilt/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/HiltExt.kt)

```
inline fun <reified T : Fragment> launchFragmentInHiltContainer(
    fragmentArgs: Bundle? = null,
    @StyleRes themeResId: Int = R.style.FragmentScenarioEmptyFragmentActivityTheme,
    crossinline action: Fragment.() -> Unit = {}
) {
    val startActivityIntent = Intent.makeMainActivity(
        ComponentName(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
            HiltTestActivity::class.java
        )
    ).putExtra(EmptyFragmentActivity.THEME_EXTRAS_BUNDLE_KEY, themeResId)

    ActivityScenario.launch<HiltTestActivity>(startActivityIntent).onActivity { activity ->
        val fragment: Fragment = activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(T::class.java.classLoader),
            T::class.java.name
        )
        fragment.arguments = fragmentArgs
        activity.supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "")
            .commitNow()

        fragment.action()
    }
}
```

[(I also have their custom runner)](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-hilt/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/CustomTestRunner.kt)

[I also have a debug source set that contains HiltTestActivity like here, alongside debug manifest.](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/tree/dev-hilt/app/src/debug)

Besides this, I'd like to somehow inject and initialize my NavigationManager (wrapper class around navController) in my Activity. Is there a way to achieve this? When I tried to use my MainActivity for tests I kept getting errors because my lateinit @Injects weren't getting initialized...

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding;

    private lateinit var navController : NavController
    @Inject
    lateinit var navManager: NavManager

    private fun initNavManager() {
        navManager.setOnNavEvent {
            navController.navigate(it)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I had to use

```
    hilt {
        enableTransformForLocalTests = true
    }
```

Since the Roboelectric/ Hilt has 20 bugs currently being tracked it was hard to pinpoint what workaround was the case :)

Answer (score 0):

I was importing kapt twice. Removing one solved it.

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
```